# google server in backgroind trask c#

Tags: c#, push-notification, google-api, windows-phone-8.1, background-agents

I am working on a windows phone 8.1 project that pulls data from google server (Blogger, and Gmail). I want to have a background agent the checks the server for new data and notifies user with a push notification. I've created a Windows Runtime Component project hoping I could handle the server side of the project (Authentication, saving credentials, ... ) in the windows runtime so I could call it from anywhere without having to have multiple servers here and there, but for so many reasons it is not possible, 
Is there anyway that I can authenticate the user in the main app and use the servers in the background agents for notifications ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite clear on your requirements but Windows Phone 8.1 does not really allow a constantly running background process that checks for notifications. Try this and see if it fits your needs;

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm